# Can Pandas handle large CSV file using Concat? - Combine CSV files

Tags: python

this is the code which combines CSV files ,
Can it handle Large CSV files ?

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import glob

li = []

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    df['filename']=str(filename)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

frame.to_csv('combinedFILE.csv')
```

Comment: How many rows do you define as 'large?'

Comment: 2gb csv files .!!